# How to rewrite aiohttp websocket handler to sanic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp, sanic

I have the following `websocket handler` in my aiohttp project:

```
async def websocket_handler(request):
     ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
     await ws.prepare(request)
     request.app['websockets'].append(ws)

     async for msg in ws:
         if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
             if msg.data == 'close':
                 await ws.close()

         elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.ERROR:
             logger.info('ws connection closed with exception %s' %
                            ws.exception())

     request.app['websockets'].remove(ws)
     return ws
```

But now I wanna to switch to `sanic` framework. How to rewrite this method? I don't understand how to do this from this [tutorial](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/routing.html#websocket-routes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bp.websocket('/websocket_handler')
    async def websocket_handler(_, ws):
        self.app['web_socket'].append(ws)
        while True:
            try:
                await ws.recv()
            except ConnectionClosed:
                break

        self.app['web_socket'].remove(ws)
```